# Prevent CLion from reordering includes while using Clang-Format

Tags: include, clion, clang-format

In my project I need to have one header included before the other. I've come to appreciate CLion's Auto-Indent feature but would still like to use Clang-Format via the plugin. Is there a way to be able to use both (possibly be disabling the reordering of includes) or do I have to chose between one of them?

Answer (score 0):

To disable `clang-format` from re-ordering your includes, you can set the style option `SortIncludes: false`. See the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for details.